How would you go about the steel columns being adjacent where an expansion joint is expected?
The building is a steel building with a composite slab.
The expansion joint is required because the building is 60m in length.
The problem is where the expansion joint is expected, the columns are large and unlike concrete buildings you cannot move the beam to the extremity and deal with an eccentric beam.
In steel the flanges governs the space.
So how would you go about this?
Thank you
